# Parse analytic explorer won't show custom events data since December 8th

Tags: parse-platform

Parse analytic explorer won't show custom events data since December 8th.

I do see results result before that time frame
I also there is custom events happening from the events tab -
but I can't see their data without the explorer functioning

Comment: This is happening to me too. Tagging with Parse.com

Comment: Is empty since December 8th for you as well? Where can I reach parse for support?

Comment: This is their main link for support: https://parse.com/help#report

There is a link for "contact" in the middle of the page. I tried this and received the following: 

Sorry, the link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed.
Search for bugs create on developers.facebook.com

A search turns up lots of noise, and I gave up. :(

Comment: its fixed for us now - after contating the face book bug system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting parse they said they fixed the issue although some data is lost - now its working

Comment: This is one of the reasons why we are moving away from Parse.